# Removing duplicates in one column

Tags: sql

I'm working in SQL and have the following table (named table1):

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| D | A |
| E | A |
| F | A |
| G | B |
| H | B |
| I | B |
| J | C |
| K | C |
| L | C |

and I would like it to return:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| D | A |
| G | B |
| J | C |

I am looking for an SQL query that returns the first value in col1 for each distinct value in col2. Basically I am looking to only retrieve one value for each distinct value in col2 and remove any duplicates in col2. I am looking for a query that I would be able to apply to other tables where I might not know the positions of the distinct values. Thanks for in advance for any help!

Comment: Is it important to return a specific value from col1?  In the example you give, you're showing the first value that corresponds to the col2 value - would col1 values of "D", "H", and "L" be equally valid?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT MIN(col1) col1, col2 FROM table1 
GROUP BY col2
```